# Converting time to minutes HH:MM:SS format

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a trouble converting a time in HH:MM:SS format to minutes. Here's my code;

```
For i = 2 To lastrow

    Sheets("RAW").Cells(i, 7).NumberFormat = "General"
    Sheets("RAW").Cells(i, lastcol) = Sheets("RAW").Cells(i, 7).Value * 1440

Next
```

My time looks like this: *00:40:38* The code always gives a **Type Mismatch** error. Any response would be appreciated.

Comment: which line gives you the error? BTW `Sheets("RAW").Cells(i, 7).NumberFormat = "General"` should be as `Sheets("RAW").Cells(i, lastcol).NumberFormat = "General"` because that is where you want the output?

Comment: Also try using `Val(Sheets("RAW").Cells(i, 7).Value) * 1440`

Comment: Thanks! using Val worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the function you are looking for is TimeValue to get the time from a string:

```
Sheets("RAW").Cells(i, lastcol).Value2 = _
    Hour(TimeValue(Sheets("RAW").Cells(i, 7).Value2)) * 60 _
    + Minute(TimeValue(Sheets("RAW").Cells(i, 7).Value2))
```